# How to call click() for element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I am using a lightgallery plugin where the `click` event is defined as:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[rel^=lightbox], area[rel^=lightbox], a[data-lightbox], area[data-lightbox]', function(event) {
    self.start($(event.currentTarget));
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

However, when I try to call the event like this:

```
$(".catalog-content a[data-lightbox='test']").first().trigger('click');
```

... it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong? How can I trigger the `click` event?

Example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wHJ8E/1/)

Comment: Is `$(".catalog-content a[data-lightbox='test']")` dynamically generated?

Comment: I guess you don't need `first()` in your call!

Comment: Dhaval Marthak, i need click only on first link!

Comment: @Buboon , Baboon , why dont  u post jsFiddle so we can see ur problem ? include External Your js also

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wHJ8E/1/

Comment: you haven't any thing with .catalog-content class?

Comment: Why so many votes to this unclear question?

Comment: And about this high visit number? Do we speak about?!

Answer (score 1):

To "simulate a click" using jQuery, you are correct in that you can just use the [`.trigger(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method:

```
$(".myClass").trigger("click");
```

**The real issue is that you are "clicking" something that doesn't exist.** There *is no* `".catalog-content a[data-lightbox='test'` element. As [Velthune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980344/velthune) suggests, you can add the `.catalog-content` class to the `div` container to fix this; however, note that there also is no `a[data-lightbox='test']` element.

Instead, in your Fiddle you define the following:

```
<a href="http://..." data-lightbox="350xi" id="test">
    something
</a>
```

So you actually just want to click on the first `a` element with a `data-lightbox` attribute of "350xi":

```
$("a[data-lightbox='350xi']").first().trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey i have gone through the jsfiddle and updated it please go through it..

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".cars-container a[rel!='']").click(function() {
        var rel = $(this).attr("rel"); 
        $(".cars-container a[data-lightbox='" + rel + "']:first").trigger('click');
    });
});
```

click below jsfiddle link to see the working example:-
http://jsfiddle.net/wHJ8E/3/

Comment: @Buboon what you want to do when click on `.cars-container a[rel!='']`?

Comment: @Manwal start a galery whith data-lightbox="relattribute"

Comment: @Buboon **start a gallery** from lightbox?? What that mean??

Comment: it's lightgallery plugin, I mean i need simulate click on <a href=".." data-lightbox="gallery">test</a>

Answer (score 0):

Your code in fiddle can't work.

1) Either use a different selector as Devendra suggested.
2) Or add the `.catalog-content` class to the `div` container:

```
<div class="cars-container catalog-content">
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wHJ8E/4/)**

3) Both Devendra and I can't understand.